# Unity Remote 4 mac/android not working

Tags: android, macos, unity-game-engine

I am trying to run "unity remote 4" test project (http://u3d.as/content/unity-technologies/unity-remote-4/7PZ) on Unity Free for Mac.

1. I have "Unity Remote 4" installed on Samsung galaxy.
2. I have android SDK installed, `adb devices` command returns `0019e6197e378e  device`.
3. I have turned on all necessary developer options on the phone.
4. When I press Play in Unity, it says `accepted incoming socket`.

But nothing shows up on app but the welcome screen asking me to press Play in Unity.

Comment: In editor go to Edit->Project Settings->Editor and under Unity Remote select what device to use

Comment: In Unity under preferences set the path to the Android SDK.

Comment: Stay Awake and Allow Mock Locations are all enabled.

Comment: choose the option Media device (MTP) instead of Camera(PTP)

Comment: @user2320445 - all things you mentioned are set correctly

Comment: unity version must be above 4.5 and it doesnt work with unity free

Comment: Ensure to restart the editor after connection

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you might be missing

1. Go to Edit Menu:- Project Setting:- Editor.
2. Under Unity Remote: Device choose "Any Android Device".
3. Connect your android device through usb cable.
4. Run unity Remote on your android device.
5. Now press play button in unity.

It will launch your game in android device.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure no android emulator (bluestack, genimotion etc) is running in background. Sometimes priority of emulator gets higher than device and operations like "Build & run" or debugging etc starts producing their outputs on emulator rather than device :)